# ASP.NET Validators No Longer Work Correctly After Changing Name of Input Control To Validate

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an input control on which I had to add "runat=server" so that I could specify ASP.NET validators on it.

The input control is part of a row.  The user can add as many rows as he likes by clicking on a button.  This is carried out using JavaScript.  For the sake of identification, each input control is named (name=) using the following naming convention:

"inputControl_" + counter

Since the "runat=server" tag changes the ids and names of controls, it could be stated that I am overwriting the name of the control using JavaScript whenever a new row is added.  The only problem now is that the ASP.NET validators always fail, even if the input is correct.

It seems that changing the name using JavaScript is causing the issue.  Unfortunately, I have to change the name since I am using Request.Form in the code-behind to get the value of each input control.

How can I get around this please?  Not using Request.Form is not an option.  Thanks.

Comment: I added "runat=server" on the input control.

Comment: No worries.  I had to add the runat="server" tag so that I could specify ASP.NET validators on the input control.

Comment: I would look at using the inbuilt AJAX handling through ASP.NET, that way the validators can be created on the server correctly, and when the page is posted back, you're not going to get issues with the control tree being different

Comment: Thanks freefaller.  Unfortunately, I have never used inbuilt AJAX handling to do this.  Could you please direct me to a good tutorial as I don't know what to search for exactly?  Many thanks :)

Comment: What do you think of this article http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/ajax-validate/?  Is this what Isshould be looking for?  Thanks.

Comment: Not really - I was thinking more along the lines of using the `<asp:UpdatePanel>`.  The tutorial you have there is just general AJAX using a different library - I think you'd be better off using the built in ASP.NET functionality.  I will write a brief answer to give you an idea

Comment: I presume the ASP.NET AJAX method wasn't a goer then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're better off using the inbuilt ASP.NET AJAX functionality.

As a starter, you need to have `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />` located on your page somewhere.

Then you should encapsulate your mark-up that deals with the addition of new rows inside of a `<asp:UpdatePanel>`.  This very useful control allows you to effectively post-back the page to the server, and deal with events as you normally would - but instead of the page refreshing, the ASP.NET code automatically does everything through AJAX seamlessly.

The content contained within the `<ContentTemplate>` section will automatically be replaced when the server sends back it's updated information... including new controls, validators, etc.

It takes a little getting your head around which buttons will cause a full page post-back, and which will cause the UpdatePanel to post-back... but they are generally controlled within the `<Triggers>` section (within `<asp:UpdatePanel>`).

There are [some tutorials here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax) which should hopefully give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

Also change the "ControlToValidate" property respective to your new IDs of your controls.

And if you are validating the controls using javascript or jquery then use `$("#<%= YourControlID.ClientID %>")` to refer it.

Comment: Hmm..  Isn't the ControlToValidate property specified on the ID rather than the name?